# How to display the chart by series in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

***index.tsx***

```
    const [ data, setData ] = useState({});
    const [ dataChart, setDataChart] = useState({});
    const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false);
 const fetchChartDetail = useCallback(async (data?) => {
        if (data && Object.keys(data).length > 0 && data['data'].length > 0) {
            data['data'].map(async (res) => {
                try {
                    await getAll({start: 1, length: 45, sensor: data.sensor}).then((response) => {
                        let DATA = {
                            ...response,
                            id: res['id'],
                            sensor: res['sensor'],
                            chart: [{
                                ...configChart,
                                data: response && response['data'] ? response['data']['data'] : []
                            }]
                        }

                        if (res.spinning) {
                            res['spinning'] = false;
                        }
                        const data = {...res, chart: [{
                                ...configChart,
                                data: response && response['data'] ? response['data']['data'] : []
                            }]};

                            if (!res.spinning) setDataChart(DATA);
                    });
                } catch (err) {
                    setError(err);
                }
            })
        }
    },[])
    const fetchData = useCallback(async (params?, status?) => {
        try {
            await getLatest().then((response) => {
                let DATA = response['data']['data'];
                DATA = Object.values(DATA.map((obj) => {
                    return {
                        ...obj,
                        spinning: true,
                    }
                }));

                response['data']['data'] = DATA;
                
                if (!status) {
                    setData(response['data']);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    fetchChartDetail(response['data']);
                }
            })
        }catch(err) {
            setError(err)
        }
    },[])

    useEffect(() => {
        let ignore = false;
        setIsLoading(true)
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            fetchData(null, ignore);
        });
        return () => {
            ignore = true;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        };
    }, [fetchData]);

return (
        <>
            {
                isLoading ? (<Loading src={`/images/icons/gif/loader.gif`} imgStyle={imgStyle} />) :
                <div className="md:flex content-center flex-wrap -mx-2 p-3">
                    {
                        data && Object.keys(data).length > 0 && data['data'].length > 0 ? 
                        (
                            data && data['data'].map((item, idx) => (
                                <div key={idx} className="md:flex md:w-1/2 lg:w-1/2 xl:w-1/3 px-2 py-2">
                                    <div className="md:flex-1 p-4 rounded shadow-lg bg-white border-b border-r border-grey-dark" onClick={() => routeDetail(router, item)}>
                                       <div className="flex flex-col">
                                            <Room config={{ item: item, ...configRoom }} index={idx} />
                                       </div>
                                       <div>
                                            <Echart config={dataChart && dataChart['chart'] ? dataChart['chart'] : [configChart]} loading={item.spinning} colors={colors} dataZoom={true} />
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))
                        ) : ('NO DATA')
                    }
                </div>
            }
        </>
    );
```

What I'm trying to do here is to display the line chart by series or if the data already complete then it will display the data. but my problem is for example I have 3 chart then after fetch the first all data from chart 1 it will display then the next fetching data is chart 2 but instead it will display the data chart 2 on chart 2 it will display the data of chart 1 in chat 2, then the data of chart 1 is empty.

on the console it will be like this when it console the `dataChart`
first load

```
{ data: [...], name: 'chart1'}
{ data: [], name: 'chart2'}
{ data: [], name: 'chart3'}
```

second load

```
{ data: [], name: 'chart1'}
{ data: [...], name: 'chart2'}
{ data: [], name: 'chart3'}
```

third load

```
{ data: [], name: 'chart1'}
{ data: [], name: 'chart2'}
{ data: [...], name: 'chart3'}
```

where it should be like this:

first load

```
{ data: [...], name: 'chart1'}
```

second load

```
{ data: [...], name: 'chart1'}
{ data: [...], name: 'chart2'}
```

third load

```
{ data: [...], name: 'chart1'}
{ data: [...], name: 'chart2'}
{ data: [...], name: 'chart3'}
```

Comment: Have you tried feeding `dataChart` & `setDataChart` to your callback dependency lists?

Comment: @TobiahRex so instead of ```setDataChart```, It should be set on the ```dataChart```?

Comment: No. Try giving your `dataChart` to your `fetchChartDetail` & `fetchChartData` dependency array `}, [dataChart])`. Currently they're empty, `}, []);`

Comment: it work, but on the line chart display when It already fetch all the data it only display one data. which is the first data.

Comment: What I did is like this ```<Echart config={dataChart && dataChart['chart'] && dataChart['id'] === item.id ? dataChart['chart'] : [configChart]} loading={item.spinning} colors={colors} dataZoom={true} />```